# Scrolling issues with chrome

Tags: 16.04, mouse, google-chrome, touchpad, multi-touch

So I recently started using Ubuntu (16.04) over Windows on my Thinkpad Yoga 14. Everything is working perfectly and I'm loving it so far but, I've been using Chrome my whole life and now when I try to scroll with two fingers is jumping to the beginning of the page, basically I scroll to the middle of a web page, then wait a few seconds and try to scroll again and jumps to the very top of the page. I also noticed that this only happens in chrome. I enabled the smooth scrolling flag in chrome and nothing. Is there any way to fix this? Or should I use another browser? If so, which one is a good option? Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: may caused by extension  try in  incognito mode see what happen and in system setting -> mouse & touchpad  insure that natural scrolling is disabled

Comment: I have the same issue, I have a T61 thinkpad. I notice it happens consistently when I am scrolling down a long page like then middle click to open a link in a new tab, then try to continue scrolling down, it will shoot to the top of the page.

Comment: Another way to trigger this is clicking anywhere on the page, then attempting to scroll again. I'm also using a Thinkpad.

Comment: @MohamedSlama That doesn't fix it. It's a relatively recent problem too.

Comment: Also seeing this issue. It's driving me up the wall!

Comment: Same here! Thanks @Hemm this is exactly how to reproduce the bug

Comment: It looks like the devs for Chromium are working on fixing this and hoping to merge it as soon as possible: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=609748

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thinkpad T460P: Scrolling jumps to top on 2 finger touch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/797057/thinkpad-t460p-scrolling-jumps-to-top-on-2-finger-touch)

Answer (score 1):

for a temporary solution, you may try 'Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller' from the chrome web store. i got the same problem with the jumping websites and am the extentions provides settings to configure the speed etc.to scroll through sites. but it may not be the best solution.

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.