# Thinkpad T460P: Scrolling jumps to top on 2 finger touch

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, touchpad, thinkpad

I've noticed in Chrome at least, if I take my fingers off my touchpad for a few seconds, and put them back down, there's a very good chance it triggers something that scrolls to the top of the page immediately (almost like pressing the Home key).

Is this a feature I can disable?

Comment: Maybe try a newer kernel just to see if it's fixed upstream? http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: I'll give this a shot. I also just noticed the scroll jumping happens to the end of the page as well if I start the two-finger scroll down motion. It must be that initial direction I move in that causes it to jump.

Comment: My X1 carbon (2015, so last generation) works perfectly. So will yours. But it's quite new hardware, so a newer kernel might do some good :)

Comment: Good call, I'll report back if it works! Just set up 4.6.3. Had to update to `nvidia-367` though.

Comment: Still happening :/

Comment: I just noticed a way to reproduce this behavior, and it's only in Chrome. If I "flick" two fingers to scroll, and click while it's still smooth scrolling (using the buttons) it jumps in the same way.

Comment: Strange, does not happen here :/

If it's only in chrome, maybe try turning off smooth scrolling in about:flags ?

Answer (score 3):

This bug is fixed in Chrome 52: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Xh9GV7jNymo
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=609748

Until then, the 'solution' I use is to place one finger on the trackpad before the other. Then you can scroll without jumping.